# ES6 pass function as parameter example

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I don't know JS/ES6 well enough to describe my question in code. So most of this question is conceptually and in pseudo code.

Say I have a `Contractor` class like this:

```
class Contractor {
 constructor(jobFn) {
    // save jobFn;
  }

  dailyRoutine() {
    // let result = DriveToWork()
    const result = 6
    DoTheJob(result)
    DriveBackHome()
  }

}
```

The problem is, what the `DoTheJob()` does might be different things in different places.

So in place A, it could be

```
he = new Contractor(write_front_end(with, this, and that))
```

And in place B, it could be

```
he = new Contractor(fix_backend_node(with, express))
```

I.e., the behavior need to be passed in during the constructor, and the action might need to take different kind and different amount of parameters.

Would such thing be possible with ES6?
Please show ES6 code that can pass function with different kind and different amount of parameters through the constructor to `DoTheJob()`.

Further, the challenge is that the `jobFn` need to be a ***Curried*** function, meaning there is one or more parameter missing to do the `DoTheJob` job. Say if the `jobFn` is passed with *Curried* `add(3)`, then `DoTheJob` will do UncurriedAdd of `add(3, 6)`; if then `jobFn` is passed with *Curried* `multiple(5)`, then `DoTheJob` will do Uncurried of `multiple(5, 6)`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign the passed function to `this.DoTheJob`, and then call `this.DoTheJob` inside `dailyRoutine`:

```js
class Contractor {
  constructor(jobFn) {
    this.DoTheJob = jobFn;
  }
  dailyRoutine() {
    // DriveToWork()
    this.DoTheJob();
    // DriveBackHome()
  }
}

const c1 = new Contractor(() => console.log('doing job A'));
c1.dailyRoutine();

const c2 = new Contractor(() => console.log('doing job B'));
c2.dailyRoutine();

// c1 again:
c1.dailyRoutine();

// feel free to reference any in-scope variables in the passed function,
// no need to pass the variables as additional parameters
const data = 'data';
const c3 = new Contractor(() => console.log('data is', data));
c3.dailyRoutine();
```

If `dailyRoutine` needs to be invoked with data that needs to be sent to the passed `doTheJob` function, just define the needed arguments in the function you pass, there's no need for actual currying here:

```js
class Contractor {
  constructor(jobFn) {
    this.DoTheJob = jobFn;
  }
  dailyRoutine(doJobArg) {
    this.DoTheJob(doJobArg);
  }
}

// feel free to reference any in-scope variables in the passed function,
// no need to pass the variables as additional parameters
const data = 'data';
const c3 = new Contractor((arg) => console.log('data is', data, 'and arg is', arg));
c3.dailyRoutine('argDoTheJobIsCalledWith');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. While trying to apply to my real case, I realized that the `jobFn` need to be a ***Curried*** function, meaning there is one or more parameter missing to do the `DoTheJob` job. I'll update my question.

Comment: See edit, pretty sure actual currying isn't necessary, you can just define another parameter (or few) as needed, and call the function with the additional info that needs to be passed in

Comment: Wonderful, wonderful! Splendid, and simple -- I was about to say I've thought of a clumsy way of doing it, but before I start, you've already given the updated answer. THANKS A LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I may advise you that it's better to give the *predicate*  to `dailyRoutine`, because this way you'll be able to reuse the same instance and give different predicates.

Anyway, there's a pure OOP solution for this, using method polymorphism, the JavaScript way (aka duck typing):

```js
class Contractor {
  driveBackHome() {}

  dailyRoutine() {
    const result = 6

    this.doTheJob(result)
    this.driveBackHome()
  }
}

class SpecializedContractorA extends Contractor {
  doTheJob(result) {
    console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', result)
  }
}

class SpecializedContractorB extends Contractor {
  doTheJob(result) {
    console.log('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', result)
  }
}

const a = new SpecializedContractorA()
a.dailyRoutine()

const b = new SpecializedContractorB()
b.dailyRoutine()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the simplicity and for focusing on my question, I omitted the gory details of my real case, when the class I'm using is at the 4th level of sub class D: A <- B <- C <- D, whereas the `dailyRoutine` is defined at the 2nd level (B). Since I believe multiple-inherit is not supported by JS/ES6, I think passing function with different kind and different amount of parameters  would be the best approach.

Comment: @xpt I still see that you don't need multi-inheritance. Why? Duck typing works flawlessly here: `dailyRoutine` is in `B`, and you define `doTheJob` in the 8th level... no problem: `if(this.doTheJob) this.doTheJob (result)`. Do you get the idea? In a dynamically-typed language you're free to do something if it's there.

Comment: Hmm... I guess different people architect things differently. For me, _reusing_ the same `D` in different scenarios by passing different functions (with different parameters) seems to be more preferable to me. I view it more cleaner personally, as I might need to use it in ten different scenarios but don't what to create ten different sub classes just for that. But thanks for helping -- I'm sure there will be people who will agree with you...

Comment: @xpt From my stand point, your approach is odd: it's not OOP nor FP. It's a shortcut. But if you're confortable with it, you're who's implementing the project :D You're welcome.